# How to make Galaxy Tab as portable WiFi hotspot?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, wifi-hotspot

I am a new user of Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (GT - P5100). Is there any way to use my Galaxy Tab as portable WiFi hotspot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this as [source](http://mobileoffice.about.com/od/phonesformobileworkers/a/How-To-Use-Your-Android-Phone-As-A-Portable-Wi-Fi-Hotspot.htm)

Procedure-

Turn on the Portable Wi-Fi Hotspot on your Android smartphone (or tablet)

> 1. Go to the Settings screen on your Android phone. You can get there
>      by pressing the menu button on your device when you're on the  home
>      screen, then tapping "Settings".
> 2. At the Settings screen, tap the "Wireless & networks" option.
> 3. You should see an option for "Portable Wi-Fi hotspot". Click the
>      check mark beside it to turn on the hotspot and your phone will
>
>    start acting like a wireless access point. (You should see a
>      message  in the notification bar when it's activated.)
> 4. To adjust and check the settings for the hotspot, tap the aptly
>      named "Portable Wi-Fi hotspot settings" option. You'll need to  do
>      this if you don't know the default password that will be created 
>      for your hotspot so you can make a note of it for connecting your 
>      other devices.
> 5. You can change the default password, security level, router name
>      (SSID), and also manage users connected wirelessly to your  phone in
>      the Wi-Fi hotspot settings.